# Как прикрутить GraphViz к проекту в AndroidStudio?

Tags: java, android, graphviz

В приложении для Андроид требуется строить блок схемы.

Нашел GraphViz, но как его использовать при программировании на Java? Нужны примеры.

Ссылка: https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz-java

Из описания:
Logging

Graphviz-java uses the SLF4J facade to log. Users must therefore provide a logging implementation like LOGBack

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

or Log4j

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Но где это надо прописать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не все что Java можно "прикрутить" к Android проекту.
Конкретно в этом, если глянуть в pom.xml, найдете как минимум нативные x86 зависимости.

Так что если автор библиотеки не заявляет, что это работает на Android, ищите дальше.

Comment: Понятно. Придется искать дальше.